# Linux Tunnell Through Nat Via Custom Proxy

Tags: linux, networking, ssl, proxy, stunnel

I am currently working on some design concepts that would see me have the requirements for the following type of system.

In short I am looking at ways to Tunnel a connection through NAT similar to VPN but without the complexity.

I have a small embedded linux device that sits behind a home LAN that I would like to be able to interface with through an API that I have created.

Currently the setup I have is as follows:

- Device A (Embedded Linux) - Public IP
- Device B (Amazon Server)

I am using a REST/Json api to control Device A from Device B.

I am looking for a protocol or solution that would allow me to send two way communication from Device A and B possibly by adding a third proxy server to handle this "Tunnelled" connection.

Notes:

- Would preferably like to avoid complex VPN's and the need for the NAT device to support VPN Passthough.
- Traffic between Device A and B is small and not highly sensitive but some security like SSL would be nice.
- This is a multinode system, Hence, There are many Device A's.

Any advice as to where I should be looking would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
pjf

Comment: Wouldn't this fit better on [*ServerFault*](http://serverfault.com/) or [*SuperUser*](http://superuser.com/) ?

Comment: well the guys over at server fault sent me to stack overflow.